# Нестандартные аттрибуты html

Tags: html, html5, валидация, атрибуты

Несмотря на то что уже давно активно используется html5, всё-равно существуют ограничения на используемые атрибуты в тегах. Некоторые фрейвморки активно их используют. Например, http://vuejs.org/ использует
      `<button v-on:click="reverseMessage">Reverse Message</button>`

Атрибут даже имеет двоеточие. Все работает, но валидацию страница не проходит. Именно это меня и беспокоит. Можно ли "закрыть глаза" на то, что страница невалидна? (Старые версии ИЕ меня не интересуют)

Ну и в завершение хотелось бы ещё спросить атрибуты data-* aria-* role Насколько я понял, для пятой версии являются стандартными?

Comment: Часть про data- aria- role, лучше перенести в отдельный вопрос и уточнить до пятой версии чего

Answer (score 2):

Это не влияет ни на отображение (вплоть до IE6), ни на индексацию. Строго говоря, это всё является валидным HTML. А с другой стороны, в стандарте декларированы `data-` атрибуты и, как правило, везде есть возможность использовать их в качестве кастомных. Надо заметить, что если ваш рендеринг основан на принципе virtual dom (mithril, virtual-dom, react), то необходимость в такого рода атрибутах чаще всего полностью отпадает.

О специфике DTD-валидации можно прочитать тут:

https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/08/17/the-value-of-html-validation/